# Realization vs Random Variables in Formulae

Tags: probability, notation, random-variables

Currently reading through: [https://web.math.princeton.edu/~rvan/APC550.pdf](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Ervan/APC550.pdf). Page 8 Section 1.2.1 says:

If $X_1$, $X_2, ...$ are i.i.d random variables, then

$$ \frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{k=1} X_k - \mathbf{E}[ \frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{k=1} X_k ] \to {0} \mbox{ as } n \to \infty $$

What does summing random variables actually mean? Are the $X_k$ realizations of the random variable or is it talking about the distribution pertaining to the variables? If I think about the meaning of this equation without the notation it makes some sense - I struggle to understand this notation.

Comment: The $X_k$ are the random variables.

Comment: Thanks. Whats does a summation of random variables mean in simple terms?

Comment: its in page 2, not 8. Its stating a law of large numbers (it don't say which). And the statement is false in general without some assumptions on the $X_k$

Comment: For me, a random variable is a number written as an output of some blackbox (a function which has a "y" result without having an input $x$ where we can say $f(x)=y$). Therefore, summing $n$ outputs of $n$ similar blackboxes isn't an issue... (or the same blackbox as long as you are sure that the preceedings results do not impair the new one).

Comment: This holds when the mean is finite, so $E[X_1]=m$ where $m$ is a finite number. Since $E[X_i]$ is the same value $m$ for all $i$, it holds that $E[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i] = m$ for all $n$, so your equation can be simplified to the ordinary statement of the LLN $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k=m \quad \mbox{ with prob 1} $$  As in the answer given below, note that $X_1, ..., X_n$ are all random variables, and so their sum $(X_1+...+X_n)$ is also a random variable.  A single outcome $\omega \in \Omega$ determines all of them $X_1(\omega), X_2(\omega), ...$.

Answer (score 1):

Random variables are, by definition, functions from a *probability space* $(\Omega, {\mathcal F}, \mathbb{P})$ to (usually) the real numbers.
This fact is often concealed in elementary presentations of probability theory.

Thus, adding random variables is just adding functions. Of course you then have to understand what you mean by the left hand side above (a sequence of functions) converging to $0$.

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate on this point of view/link to some resource on this please? Does adding in this case mean: sum the functions which have the same support followed by normalization to ensure a PDF?

Answer (score 1):

The Strong LLN says that if $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ are *i.i.d. random variables* with $E(X_i)=m<\infty,$ then

$$P\left\{\omega\in\Omega\ \bigg\rvert\ \lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\left({X_1(\omega)+\cdots+X_n(\omega)\over n}\right)=m \right\}=1,\tag{1}$$

or equivalently,

$$P_X\left\{(x_1,x_2,\ldots)\in\pmb R^{\pmb N}\ \bigg\rvert\ \lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\left({x_1+\cdots+x_n\over n}\right)=m \right\}=1.\tag{2}$$

The first equation (1) makes explicit reference to some *unspecified* underlying probability space $(\Omega,\mathscr F,P)$ on which the random sequence $X=(X_1,X_2,\ldots)$ is defined as a Borel-measurable function $X:\Omega\to\pmb R^{\pmb N}.$ (Here $\pmb R^{\pmb N}$ denotes the set of all infinite sequences of real numbers.)

The second equation (2) avoids these "underlying details" of the *function* $X$ and refers only to its probability distribution $P_X$, which assigns probabilities to the Borel subsets of $\pmb R^{\pmb N}$.

In both (1) and (2), the quantities being summed are "realizations" of the coordinate random variables $X_i$, i.e. just real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Without delving into too many details, a sum of random variables is in turn another random variable. For instance, if $X$ and $Y$ are iid  Bernoulli($p$) (both defined on the same probability space), then
$X+Y$ is a new random variable with masses given by
$$P(X+Y=2)=P(X=1,Y=1)=p^2\\
P(X+Y=1)=P(X=1,Y=0)+P(X=0,Y=1)=2p(1-p)\\
P(X+Y=0)=P(X=0,Y=0)=(1-p)^2. $$

Now, as for the convergence statement you wrote, first note if $X_1,X_2,...$ are iid, we can more concisely write
$$E[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k]=E[X_1].$$

So your convergence statement is essentially saying that the sequence of random variables given by

$$X_1,\frac{1}{2}(X_1+X_2),\frac{1}{3}(X_1+X_2+X_3),...$$

"converges" to $E[X_1].$ However, it is important to understand that this convergence is ***not*** your vanilla convergence of a deterministic sequence (which wouldn't make much sense here) since, once again, the sequence in question is one of *random variables*.

There are many notions of convergence of random variables, and in your case, since that link alludes to the law of large numbers, the notion of convergence in question is either *convergence in probability* ([weak law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Weak_law)) or *almost sure convergence* ([strong law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Strong_law)). Both laws hold under some assumptions (e.g. $X_i$ iid and having finite mean), and you should study some prelims before delving into your link.

I found an elementary starter course [here](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/).